# Monitor Spring Boot App running in Docker via JMX

Tags: java, docker, jmx, docker-swarm, traefik

I am using docker swarm & Traefic to manage and deploy my containers. Unfortunately, I didn't set it up and not sure details, all I do is just deploy my app there and everything taken care of. 
I am running Spring Boot Apps, each app could have multiple instances. 
Docker file is pretty simple, 
basically

```
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /app.jar
```

And we use Traefic to manage it as well.

I am trying to connect jconsole to different apps but not sure how to do it for remote app that runs in docker swarm remotely. Locally no issues.

I read on an internet about setting JMX setting when starting java app but all information about connecting to app running in docker locally or with static IP. I imagine I do not have static IP to add to my configuration, it always assigned dynamicly.

Any advise or where to start look would be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To map multiple containers, you can use the container hostname.
When you run a container like "docker run -ti ... --hostname test1 ..." or run a service "docker service create ... name= test1...".

So, you have to hitting via hostname.

Regards.